# What is homology/cohomology of $S^n \smallsetminus S^k$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n \smallsetminus \mathbb{R}P^k$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, spheres

For $k=0, S^n \smallsetminus S^0$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$.

But, how to determine when $k$ is not equal to $0$?

Comment: What approaches have you tried to figure out the answer?

Comment: For k=0, S^n-S^0 is homotopy equivalent to wedge sum of two (n-1)-spheres. For 0<k<n,  I have no clue.

Comment: I mean, this information should be as a part of your question.  This will allow people to see what you are getting stuck on, and know what type of hints to give you to guide you toward an answer.

Comment: Are you sure about your computation ?

Comment: What you wrote for $k = 0$ is wrong. Try for $n = 1$ or $n = 2$.

Comment: Yes. I am wrong. $S^n-S^0$ will be homotopically equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ instead of  $S^{n-1} V S^{n-1}$. I have corrected my question. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

$S^n \setminus S^k$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-k-1}$. Further, $\Bbb{RP}^n \setminus \Bbb{RP}^k$ is homotopy equiavlent to $\Bbb{RP}^{n-k-1}$. These statements are straightforward to show and I will leave them to you as exercises.

Comment: Is it really "straightforward"? Are you using the decomposition $S^n \cong (S^k \times D^{n-k}) \cup_\partial (S^{n-k-1} \times D^{k+1})$?

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, obviously I'm not using that decomposition, William. Define the deformation retraction

$$f_t(x_0, \cdots, x_n) = (t x_0, \cdots, tx_k, x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_n) + (0, \cdots, 0,  \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{n-k}(x_0^2 + \cdots x_k^2)+x_{k+1}^2}, \cdots, \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{n-k}(x_0^2 + \cdots x_k^2)+x_n^2}).$$ I'm sure you can at least compute that this is a deformation retraction of $S^n \setminus S^k$ onto $S^{n-k-1}$.

The definition of this homotopy is made completely clear by thinking of literally any example you can picture. You contract by a 'straight line' to the complementary sphere to $S^k$, the one point compactification of the radial deformation retraction of $\Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^k$ onto $S^{n-k-1}$. It is also obviously Z/2 invariant, so descends to a deformation retraction downstairs. If you have difficulty with this I don't know what to tell you.